# Regex between text with different characters on NotePad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to catch the code starting with      `<div id="usermenu">` until the end of it's close tag `</div>` Can I do this with regex. See the code example

```html
<div id="logo"> LOGO   <a href="index.html"></a></div>
         <!-- REGEX STARTS HERE -->
  <div id="usermenu">
 BLA BLA BLA BLA
.......................<br/>
            <div class="another-div>LA BLA BLA BLA<div>
 BLA BLA BLA BLA
.......................<br/>
                  <div class="some-another-div>LA BLA BLA BLA<div>   
 BLA BLA BLA BLA
.......................<br/>
</div>

<!-- REGEX STOPS HERE -->
<div id="topmenu-position">TOP MENU</div>
```

Comment: Regex isn't designed to handle recursive structures like this. There might be variants of regex that have extensions to allow that sort of thing.

Comment: I have 600 static html pages that needs to updated so I can't think another way to do this

Comment: You ought to be able to find an HTML or XML parser. Or maybe even just use your web browser, manipulate the DOM from the dev console, then pull out the resulting HTML.

Comment: I suppose that with that many pages, you'll want to get a parser and write a script to do all the manipulation for you.

Comment: Maybe I can use the unique tags that way I could be sure to catch the right code like the regex gets the '<div id="usermenu">' than closes just before '<div id="topmenu-position">'

Comment: For the simple extent before the edit, my answer was fine. Now you have a bigger problem on your hand and need to go with a parser of some sort.

Comment: Could you recommend some kind of parser to deal with this issue. Thanks for your help again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works.

`<div id="usermenu">[^\<]{0,}</div>`

If you want only that which is between the tags, say for a replace, use this.

`<div id="usermenu">([^\<]{0,})</div>`

Comment: To match zero or more substrings, `{0,}` is normally just written as `*`.

Comment: You are correct. I must still harbor regex tendencies that were shaped by Textpad.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regex in Notepad++.

Make sure "Regular expression" along with `.` matches newline is checked.

```
<div id="usermenu">.*?</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the question. There is another div inside the username div so that might cause to regex stop on the fir div close tag.

Comment: This regex will only match if there are no nested tags. It side-steps the issue of matching the tag over arbitrary contents. Unfortunately, pure regex cannot solve that problem. It's not even possible in principle.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a copy of Notepad++ handy, but something like this might work:

```
(<div id="usermenu">.+?<\/div>)
```

Just make sure that you enable the dot (.) to match all newline characters.  You can test it out here http://regex101.com/ with:

```
/(<div id="usermenu">.*?<\/div>)/s
```

FWIW, s = dot (.) matches everything including newline http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers.  Just as an aside though, I would probably use an HTML parser to perform something like this.  If you're into Python, [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is one such parser.